# Ionic File Encryption

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm trying to use Ionic Native File Encryption plugin which works with Cordova Safe plugin.

However, after I add the plugin and try to run (even without using it in my code) it using `ionic cordova run android`, I get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 5s
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\User\Ionic\App\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:70968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Which @ionic/app-scripts versions are you using?

Comment: @jeffchef 3.1.9

Comment: what about your cordova version?

Comment: @jeffchef "Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0, Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2"

Comment: Have you installed the correct Android SDK version which supports 7.0.0 and above?

Comment: @jeffchef Yes, as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to install `CordovaSafe` plugin as well but I got the same error as you did.

After trying for awhile, I found out that the issue can be solved if you downgrade your cordova to a previous version.

**Try running**

> npm uninstall cordova

**And then**

> npm install -g cordova@7.1.0

Tell me if it works for you after downgrading your cordova version and creating your project with `CordovaSafe` plugin again.